# Blazor progressive web app show camera on ios

Tags: ios, typescript, blazor, mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps

I have a blazor web app which uses the camera to scan differen qr codes (using the zbar implementation for blazor). On windows in different browsers and on android in different browsers i get to see the feed the camera generates. However Ios and safari keep not showing the camera feed. my code in typescript is the following:

```
const mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio: false,
            video: {
                facingMode: 'environment',
                width: { max: 640 },
                height: { max: 480 }
            }
        });
```

and in my blazor page i have the following:

```
<video @ref="video" autoplay loop muted playsinline controls="controls"></video>
```

Safari show the controlls of the video player correctly without any problem but no camera feed. Sadly i do not have access to the debugger console to see the log from safari to see what is wrong in the page.

i found some references that the camera feed needs to be in a correct size and that the controls needed to be visible for it to work. but to no avail. On the different devices we have set the permission to camera and microphone to allow but we don't see the popup for allowing the camera feed in the browser.

Is there someone who has an idea what is wrong? We haven't tried to install a different browser yet but would that work?